# Create generated id number and check in sql database if already exist

Tags: sql, vb.net

first, i use rand() to generate unique id number and and put it in a label. 
and i want to check this rand() number in sql database if it is already exist to avoid duplications.

and use this codes

```
Private Sub generatedid()
    Try
        sqlconn.Open()
        Dim autoID As Integer = Int(Rnd() * 999999) + 1
        Dim logquery As String = "SELECT clientid FROM tbl_clientrecords WHERE ClientID = '" & autoID & "' "
        sqlcomm = New MySqlCommand(logquery, sqlconn)
        sqlread = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader

        Dim resCnt As Integer = 0
        While sqlread.Read
            resCnt += 1

        End While

        If resCnt = 1 Then
            cautoid.Text = Int(Rnd() * (Int(Rnd() * 999999) + 1))
        Else
            cautoid.Text = autoID
        End If
        sqlconn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

but when i look to generated rand() number in a label and also looking in sql database. both are the same. causing cant able to insert new data. 
help me thank you.

Comment: We use the `Random` class these days. Why would you use a random number to check the DB?

Comment: Have you never heard of IDENTITY fields? The server will do all the work to generate the ID for you. If you don't like an IDENTITY field, use a GUID. It will be distinct (unique). Either of those would be much more efficient than generating random numbers and then checking to see if it already exists (and repeating if it does), and either would work supporting multiple users (where your solution will not).

Comment: how? sorry  , im still studying vb with database. can you show a sample code of what you're saying?

Comment: i'll research that identity and guid . thanks for the info

Comment: No. You can Google *SQL Server IDENTITY* or look in Books Online to read the documentation. This is not a tutorial site, and we're not your personal research assistants. I've suggested where you should look to find a better solution; you can at least make an effort to learn about it yourself instead of just immediately writing *plz send me teh codez*.

Comment: i once use this identity where it is auto increment starting from 1 . and i dont like that way. i should move and research this GUID .

Comment: You should also always use SQL Parameters - your SELECT statement is treating the Id as string which it clearly is not.  The flaw in your scheme is that random does not mean unique.  It is the job of the DB to create unique Ids.  Also, please read [Ask] and take the [Tour]

Answer (score -1):

i did manage to create successfully id without duplicate just by looping the method

btw, still thank you for you're help

```
Dim idloop As Boolean = True
    While idloop = True
        Try
            sqlconn.Open()
            Dim autoID As Integer = Int(Rnd() * 999999) + 1
            Dim logquery As String = "SELECT clientid FROM tbl_clientrecords WHERE ClientID = '" & autoID & "' "
            sqlcomm = New MySqlCommand(logquery, sqlconn)
            sqlread = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader

            Dim resCnt As Integer = 0
            While sqlread.Read
                resCnt += 1
            End While

            If resCnt = 1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("oopsss-duplicate")
                idloop = True
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("good")
                cautoid.Text = autoID
                idloop = False
            End If
            sqlconn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error")
        End Try

    End While
```

Comment: Glad to see that you got a solution. Just be aware that this is not a good solution and you should do further study. Perhaps you could refactor your code in the future using the advice given by Ken White and Plutonix.